# how to declare user defined permissions in android

Tags: android, android-permissions

In android we use system permission but how can I create a new permission in an application, to be used by other applications.

Comment: check this below link


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816623/how-to-use-custom-permissions-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `<permission>` tag for that. [This page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#declaring) clearly explains how you can do it.