# what is the use of adding custom permission on activity in android

Tags: android

Hi I am learning android security so there I went through a topic where someone mentioned a custom permission on activity as like below :-

```
<permission android:name=”com.testpaccourierkage.mypermission” 
    android:label=”my_permission” 
    android:protectionLevel=”dangerous” 
    android:description=”@string/detonate_description” />

<application> 
    <activity 
        android:permission=”com.testpackage.mypermission”            
        android:name=”.PermissionTestClientActivity”            
        android:label=”@string/app_name”/>  
</application>
```

I could not understand the use of this. How and where we can use this concept.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17078369/few-questions-about-custom-permissions-in-android?lq=1 ) thread to know more about custom permissions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are writing a suite of apps, and you want to have an activity in one app that other apps in the suite can start, but arbitrary other third-party apps cannot start, you could use a custom permission as shown in your question.

This is rather unusual. Custom permissions in general are rather unusual, in part because they were designed for pre-installed apps and [do not work well for normal Android SDK apps](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-security/blob/master/PERMS.md).

Comment: how pre-installed apps are using this concept ? any example

Comment: @Williams: They use it the same way. The advantage is that they are pre-installed, and so their custom permission definitions are the ones that are enforced.

Comment: I still could not understand use of it. what is the need of it.

Comment: @Williams: "I still could not understand use of it" -- then do not use it. Few developers have a need for custom permissions.

Comment: yes but i want to know why few developers need custom permissions.

Comment: @Williams: Few developers write more than one app.

Comment: so if i set the protection level to dangerous then when i install that app with custom permission then android will ask that permission while installing right ?

Comment: @Williams: Let us assume two apps: App A and App B. If App A has `<permission>` for some custom `dangerous` permission, and App B has `<uses-permission>` for the same name, and App A is installed before App B, then when App B is installed, the user should be prompted for that permission, at least prior to Android 6.0.

Comment: Thanks great.. i understood :)