# Android: different permission for two activites

Tags: android, sdk, manifest

I know the basic rules of the manifest, but it works on all activites.

I have two activites in my apliccation.
I want that one have to internet access, and another not.
How can i do that?

And hardest: 
I want that one have to 3G internet access, and another can use only wi-fi.
How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to determine if WiFi is connected and act properly

```
final ConnectivityManager conectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
final NetworkInfo mWifi = conectivityManager
            .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
return mWifi.isConnected();
```

Basicly, you can't give permission to activities separatly as it's not you who are giving the permission, but the user. Thus, user give permission to the whole app and doesn't care about `activities`.

Comment: Not exact answer, but basically exactly what i need.

Answer (score 0):

You must add all permisions to your manifest. Persmissions are global. That means that you are giving permission for your application, not for every single activity. If you'll add wifi and 3g permission you can use this connection in your activities.

Answer (score 0):

You can define custom permissions in android for each different activity

You can refer these

[How to use custom permissions in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816623/how-to-use-custom-permissions-in-android)

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html