# How to enforce the custom permission on an Activity in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, permissions

I have created a custom permission in android as:

```
<permission
    android:name="com.master.me.CUSTOM_PERMISSION_TEST"
    android:description="@string/des_permission"
    android:label="labelhere">
</permission>
```

How will I enforce this in my Activity in `AndroidManifest.xml` file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use custom permissions in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816623/how-to-use-custom-permissions-in-android)

Comment: where we must enforce custom permission on an activity ?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use `android:permission` attribute into activity tag.

Like below

```
<activity android:permission="com.master.me.CUSTOM_PERMISSION_TEST"
            android:name=".YourActivity"
            android:label="@string/activity_label" />
```

And you need to add `uses-permission` to your custom permission, when your other application needs to launch this activity.

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.master.me.CUSTOM_PERMISSION_TEST"/>
```

---

[***An In-Depth Introduction to 
the Android Permission Model***](https://www.owasp.org/images/c/ca/ASDC12-An_InDepth_Introduction_to_the_Android_Permissions_Modeland_How_to_Secure_MultiComponent_Applications.pdf) is a very good article to understand permission in Android. And [How to use custom permissions in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816623/how-to-use-custom-permissions-in-android) is also a very good SO thread.

Comment: @PankajKumar: Just having a simple doubt: Does using CUSTOM_PERMISSION_TEST in an activity means that any other application which does not have this permission(CUSTOM_PERMISSION_TEST), will not be able to start this activity?

Comment: @Zax Yes you are perfect.

Comment: @Zax  And I want to add one more thing. If you add protectionLevel="signature" while defining custom permission, then even if another application declares your permission, can not access that Activity until that is signed by same certificate. Read more at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html#plevel