# Android: how to get calling application developer's public key

Tags: android, android-intent

I have following situation. Another application is calling mine (using startActivityForResult).
Since I have to be sure that the calling activity comes from developer I trust I'd like to read the developer public key and compare it with value that is hardcoded in my app.
I tried following:

```
String packageName = callingActivity.getPackageName();
String signature = null;
try {
     PackageInfo pi = manager.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
     // assumption: get the first available signature
     // actually according to Google for applications there will be always one element
     signature = pi.signatures[0]. toCharsString();
}
```

But this gives me application (not developer) signature.

Comment: I doubt there can be an API for that, since it would break security

Comment: Seems I'm wrong, since it's OK to share the public key. Please disregard my comment

Answer (score 2):

Use android custom permissions for this purpose. By defining a permission in your application, you can restrict other apps that use your activity/service  unless they have a uses-permission in their manifest. 
Read this for more info :

> http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html#Permissions

For an example:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/8817231/607968

Comment: Not really an option for me. Couple of reasons, but the main is:  http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/08/04/custom-permission-vulnerability-l-developer-preview.html