# Enforce two permissions to activity in android

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

I came across with the following issue. I have an activity that uses to permissions: recording audio and writing to external storage and returns the result to those activities that started it with an intent.
I want to make sure that only those other apps could launch it, that have both uses-permissions.
I tried the following declaration in manifest file, but it seems to be incorrect, as android does not allow double use of android permission attribute in activity.

```
<activity
    android:name="some_name"
    android:label="some_label"
    android:permission="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"
    android:permission="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
</activity>
```

Is there any way to make this possible with android?

Comment: Note that if your `<activity>` really looks as it does in your code snippet, no other apps can launch it. You have no `<intent-filter>`, and so this activity is not exported. Beyond that, while I have not tried it, you may be able to call `checkCallingPermission()` on your activity in `onCreate()` to see if the caller holds the second permission, whichever one you are not enforcing via `android:permission`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can crate a [custom permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816623/how-to-use-custom-permissions-in-android) which can be `android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO` and `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` (Both in one permission) and then put that permission in your `Activiy`.